# How to Change Redhat OpenJDK version name to make Eclipse run without an error?

Tags: eclipse, redhat-openjdk

> I have installed Redhat OpenJDK into my computer, now when I am opening the Eclipse IDE I am having the issue.

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "201-2-redhat"

How to Change Redhat OpenJDK version name to make Eclipse run without an error?

Below is the log:

```
!SESSION 2019-04-29 11:46:15.415 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745
java.version=1.8.0_201-2-redhat
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product com.rapidclipse.ide.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.rapidclipse.ide.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-04-29 11:46:18.179
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "201-2-redhat"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.rapidclipse.application.VMCheck.checkJavaVersion(VMCheck.java:64)
    at com.rapidclipse.application.VMCheck.check(VMCheck.java:17)
    at com.rapidclipse.application.RapidclipseApplication.start(RapidclipseApplication.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

Comment: Looks like it is 'rapidclipse' code that is having the problems.

Comment: I guess so, but is there any way I can change the OpenJDK version name? It is picking that name from somewhere that name, right? Same name I am seeing in CMD how to change that? As I know I just have to remove minus signs and characters.

Comment: What JDK does Rapidclipse point you to? Shouldn't you use that?

Comment: Nitin, I didn't understand what do you want to say. I cannot use Oracle JDK anymore for commercial use without paying for that. So, now we are moving our application to Redhat Open JDK that is why we need a solution.

Comment: Did you try in `eclipse.ini` add the line `-Djava.version=1.8.0_201` below the line `-vmargs` (not sure if this system property can be overwritten)? And don't forget to report it to Rapidclipse.

Comment: Howlger, Thanks for the help. But it didn't override the version name. In case of Rapidclipse, the best solution I got is : Amazon Corretto (working fine for us) can be downloaded from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html